# jQuery Accordion Wordpress Causes IE6/7 “unexpected call to method or property access”

Tags: jquery-ui

A page I'm working on, http://www.northshorern.com/questions-answers/ is giving me an error in IE6/7 on WinXP SP2:

A Runtime Error has occurred. Line XYZ. Unexpected call to method or property access.

I've narrowed the issue down to the way that the jQuery accordion elements are called, as I'm not getting this error when I simply type in the accordion children manually. The code being used is:

```
<div id="accordionWrapper">
<div id="accordion">

<?php 
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'showposts' => 10 
) );  
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h3><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <div>
        <blockquote>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>

</div>
</div>
```

So, something's not right here and can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: PHP is parse on server so it doesn't have any cross browser error. Perhaps more info about the error will help.

Comment: Since this is a Javascript error and not a WP error, it doesn't really belong on the site.  I'll migrate this to Stack Overflow for you so it can get some attention.

Comment: Thank you. Hoping to get some relief on this... usually don't ask a question unless I'm ready to throw the computer out the window. This is essentially where I'm at on this issue.